# t-sql update multiple rows using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i trying to update a column in my table for several rows at the same time.

i want get the value to update from an another table which has a foreignkey.

```
Table Table1:

Id Primary
UserNumber INT


Table Table2
Id Primary
Id_T1 ForeignKey
UserId INT
OrderNumber INT
```

can someone help with this pls?

Note: In the Table T2 i need the UserId Value Where the ordernumber has the maximum value.

for example:

```
Id_T1 UserId OrderNumber 
15    24        1 
15    55        2 
15    72        3
```

the value i want to receive is the 72.

```
i have try this:
update T1 set T1.UserNumber = T2.UserId
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
ON T1.Id = T2.IdMain
WHERE T1.Id = T2.IdMain
AND T2.OrderNumber = (SELECT MAX(T2.OrderNumber) FROM Table2)
```

**but i get this error:**

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 An aggregate may not appear in the
>   WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause
>   or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer
>   reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use alias name in inner query.
Try this:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.UserNumber = T2.UserId
FROM Table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN 
     Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Id = T2.IdMain
WHERE T1.Id = T2.IdMain
     AND T2.OrderNumber = (SELECT MAX(OrderNumber) FROM Table2)
```

Comment: yep it works for only 1 row. i have add this condition to update the multiple rows. (SELECT MAX(OrderNumber) FROM Table2 WHERE IdMain = M.Id) +1

Comment: @user2232273: It will only update 1 row (where ordernumber is maximum). Isn't that what you are looking for?